# ASP.Net: IHttpAsyncHandler and IRequiresSessionState not working

Tags: asynchronous, ihttpasynchandler

I have implemented an IHttpAsyncHandler. I am making about 5 different AJAX calls from a webpage that has widgets to that handler.

One of those widgets takes about 15 seconds to load(because of a large database query) the others should all load in under a second. The handler is responding in a synchronous manner.

I am getting very inconsistent results. The ProcessRequest method is using Session and other class level variables. **Could that be causing different requests to use the same thread instead each there own?**

I'm getting this...

Request1 ---> response 1 sec
Request2 ---> response 14 sec
Request3 ---> response 14.5 sec
Request4 ---> response 15 sec
Request5 ---> response 15.5 sec

but I'm looking for something more like this...

Request1 ---> response 1 sec
Request2 ---> response 14 sec
Request3 ---> response 1.5 sec
Request4 ---> response 2 sec
Request5 ---> response 1.5 sec

Without posting too much code my implementation of the IHttpAsyncHandler methods are pretty standard.

```
private AsyncProcessorDelegate _Delegate;

protected delegate void AsyncProcessorDelegate(HttpContext context); 

IAsyncResult IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, 
    AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
{
    _Delegate = new AsyncProcessorDelegate(ProcessRequest);

    return _Delegate.BeginInvoke(context, cb, extraData); 
}

void IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    _Delegate.EndInvoke(result); 
}
```

Putting a debug break point in my IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest method I can see that the method isn't being fired until the last Process is complete.

Also my machine.config has this entry...
    processModel autoConfig="true" with no other properties set.

I'm calling the handler like this...
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "../HTML/HtmlHandler.ashx",
        cache: true,
        dataType: "text",
        data: { html: name },
        success: function(html) {
            //$(function() {
                //console.log(tabname);
                //console.log("msg:" + msg);
                $("#" + name + "holder").html(html);
                //checkAllLoaded();
                ClientHome_init('');
            //});
        },

```
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $("#" + name + "holder").html("<span>Error retrieving widget.</span>");
        //console.log("error:" + tabname);
        //checkAllLoaded();
    }
}
```

**What else do I need to check for?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just incase someone else has this problem changing IRequiresSessionState to IReadOnlySessionState fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem here is probably not with your server code. The nature of javascript is that it is synchronous. Even when you are using asynchronous AJAX requests, I find that javascript will rarely allow you to make two HTTP requests at the same time.